# Title indentation after linebreak

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, indentation

I have a document with a few long-named sections, which break at two lines, like this:

[image]

To meet some standards I need to change indentation of these titles (after `\linebreak`) at the level of normal text:

[image]

How can I do this? I searched for a few hours on Google and here and find nothing.

**Update** I use `eskdx` package for document and its class `eskdtext`. Sections are default for this class (no redefenitions).

Comment: Which document class are you using? Are you using some redefinition of the sectional unit headings? Please add this information to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `titlesec`; the spacing parameters in `\titlespacing` are the same as those defined by the `extarticle` class.

```
\documentclass[russian,utf8]{eskdtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

% without this we get an error
\DeclareTextSymbol{\No}{T2A}{"9D}

% store the value of \parindent
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
 {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
 {\hspace*{\normalparindent}\thesection}
 {1em}
 {\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\section}
 {0pt}% space at the left
 {3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}% space before
 {2.3ex plus 2ex}% space after

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\section{Some long title which is broken into two lines}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @egreg. I already pass a document, but now I know how to do it.